# Using lapply with a function that returns a SpatialPixelsDataFrame

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp

I am trying to use a function which returns a SpatialPixelsDataFrame object using lapply and keep getting the following error

> Error in .printSpatial(x) : object 'nf' not found

My actual function reads in a csv and applies kriging, but I have found the same thing happens to even very very simple functions. I've made a simple example using the default data where using `lapply` or `list` returns this error.

So if I can't have `sp` objects in a list is there anyway I can run a function on different inputs (in my real data the csv files) to get the outputs?

```r
  library(sp)

data(meuse.grid)

datalist <- list(meuse.grid, meuse.grid)

testout1 <- lapply(datalist,SpatialPixelsDataFrame,points = meuse.grid[c("x", "y")])
testout1 
[[1]]
class       : SpatialPixelsDataFrame 
dimensions  : 104, 78, 3103, 7  (nrow, ncol, npixels, nlayers)
resolution  : 40, 40  (x, y)
Error in .printSpatial(x) : object 'nf' not found


grid1 = SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points = meuse.grid[c("x", "y")], data = meuse.grid)
grid2 = SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points = meuse.grid[c("x", "y")], data = meuse.grid)
 # both grid 1 and grid two successfully return grids - don't want to print the whole thing

testout2 <- list(grid1,grid2)
testout2
[[1]]
class       : SpatialPixelsDataFrame 
dimensions  : 104, 78, 3103, 7  (nrow, ncol, npixels, nlayers)
resolution  : 40, 40  (x, y)
Error in .printSpatial(x) : object 'nf' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. I'm in a fresh R session with `sp` v1.3-1

Comment: Hmm, thank you, yes I have `raster` loaded as well. Without it loaded it seems to work fine. Unfortunately I need raster for other parts of the script :(

Comment: Maybe you can split things into two scripts. Or try to build an example that includes the `raster` functions you need

Comment: Thanks, I will try and separate out the raster stuff and update the question if I can't